# "Protective Layers" according to Hindu Scriptures

Tags: scripture, science

I was reading a post about cosmic science and I found that [Protective Layers  Already Mentioned in Vedas](http://haribhakt.com/cosmic-science-of-today-is-based-on-vedic-hindu-texts-written-thousands-of-years-ago/#Protective_Layers_Ozone_Already_Mentioned_in_Vedas).

So my question is- Which Hindu scriptures define this?

<sub>Please note that, I am not asking about scientific speculation.</sub>

Comment: kahin mentioned nhi lagti. kisne kaha tumse?

Comment: @Fire. read the link.

Comment: Atmosphere is different from Ozone layer. Where is $O_{3}$ mentioned?

Comment: [Protective Layers (Ozone) Already Mentioned in Vedas](http://haribhakt.com/cosmic-science-of-today-is-based-on-vedic-hindu-texts-written-thousands-of-years-ago/#Protective_Layers_Ozone_Already_Mentioned_in_Vedas)

Protection of Earth from Ultraviolet rays: After the formation of the earth, Brahma created atmosphere in group of seven, from that formation oceans began to exist, and the first form of life appeared on the planet.